# Śrī Rudram Laghunyāsa is found in which scripture?

Tags: vedas, shiva, rudra

These mantras are part of the Śrī Rudram Laghunyāsa -

**ॐ अथात्मानग्ं शिवात्मानग् श्री रुद्ररूपं ध्यायेत् ॥**
**शुद्धस्फटिक सङ्काशं त्रिनेत्रं पञ्च वक्त्रकम् ।**
**गङ्गाधरं दशभुजं सर्वाभरण भूषितम् ॥**

**नीलग्रीवं शशाङ्काङ्कं नाग यज्ञोप वीतिनम् ।**
**व्याघ्र चर्मोत्तरीयं च वरेण्यमभय प्रदम् ॥**

**कमण्डल्-वक्ष सूत्राणां धारिणं शूलपाणिनम् ।**
**ज्वलन्तं पिङ्गलजटा शिखा मुद्द्योत धारिणम् ॥**

**वृष स्कन्ध समारूढम् उमा देहार्थ धारिणम् ।**
**अमृतेनाप्लुतं शान्तं दिव्यभोग समन्वितम् ॥**

In which scripture do these mantras appear?[image]

**Namah Śivāya.**

Answer (score 1):

Partly from the Tāittirīya-brāhmaṇá (3.10.8.4-10), along with some later insertions.

Reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G0RMh_L16Jg

Comment: Thanks alot ! , I had two questions  - is "Nīlagrīva" same as "Nīlakaṇṭha" and what is the accurate meaning of "Kṛttivāsa". Thanks!